# Find the first 5 terms of the expansion in a power series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Find the first 5 terms of the expansion in a power series
$$y′=xe^{x}+2y^{2}$$

I've got a riccati equation $$ x e^{x}+2y^{2},  y(0)=0$$
After solving: $$y=e^{x}(x-1)+\frac{2}{3}y^{3} - 1$$

And I don't know how to go forward. Please help me.

Comment: Your "After solving" is not correct. Most terms are correct, but the integral of $y^2\; dx$ is not $ y^3/3$

Comment: hmm..I thought it correct, but y'=xe^x + 2y^2 can be solved without second summand, can't it?

Comment: No, you are integrating everything with respect to $x$.  Take the simpler $y'=y$, which is solved by $y=Ae^x$.  Your technique would give us $y=\frac {y^2}2$ which is not at all the same.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand that, but with or without mistakes I've got a correct answer. Thanks for a correction, I'll be more attentive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You assume that there exist $a_i$ such that $$y = a_0 +a_1x + a_2x^2 + \cdots.$$
From here it is very easy to calculate power series expansions for $y', xe^x,$ and $2y^2$.  Then you equate like powers of $x$ on both sides of the equality to get a relation between the $a_i$, and get a sequence of fairly simple equations in the $a_i$.  The initial condition $y(0)=0$ tells you immediately that $a_0 = 0$ and from there you can usually get the other coefficients.
Once you have $a_0,\ldots a_4$, you have the answer to the question.

---

To take a much simpler example that gives an idea of the method, suppose the equation were $$y' = y + 1$$ with the initial condition $y(0) = 0$.

We start with:

$$\begin{array}{rlrrr}
y &= &a_0 &+a_1x &+ a_2x^2 &+ \cdots \\
y+1 &=& 1+ a_0 &+a_1x &+ a_2x^2 &+ \cdots \\
y' &=& a_1 &+2a_2x &+ 3a_3x^2 &+ \cdots 
\end{array}$$

Then equating the last two we have $$a_1 + 2a_2x + 3a_3x^2 + \cdots = 1 + a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + \cdots$$

and equating coefficients of like powers gives equations in the $a_i$:
$$
\begin{align}
a_1 & =& 1+a_0\\
2a_2 & = &a_1 \\
3a_3 & = & a_2\\
&\vdots&
\end{align}
$$

Now $y(0) = 0$ tells us immediately that $a_0 = 0$.  And the equations above then give us $a_1 = 1, a_2 = \frac12, a_3 = \frac16,\ldots$.  So the series for $y$ is $$y = x + \frac12x^2 + \frac16x^3 + \cdots$$

which is in fact the power series for $y=e^x-1$.

Comment: Thank you very much! You have completely solved my problem.

Comment: I am glad that I could help.