# Derive the recursion relation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, recursion

> Consider the nonhomogeneous linear equation $y' = 2y/(1-x) + f(x)$. It is singular at $x=1$, of course, but it is regular at $x=0$ if (the known function) $f(x)$ is analytic there.  Assume $y(x) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty a_mx^m$ and $f(x) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty b_mx^m$.
>
> (**d**) Substitute these series directly into the differential equation and, recalling the geometric series $1/(1-x) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty x^m$, derive the recursion relation $a_n =\frac2n\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}a_r + b_{n-1}/n$.

([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJ7pA.png))

I'm having some trouble to derive the recursion relation shown in the screenshot.

Comment: Could you be more specific regarding the trouble you're having?

Comment: I gave an example of a similar thing, but for a simpler example, in [Find the first 5 terms of the expansion in a power series](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397485/find-the-first-5-terms-of-the-expansion-in-a-power-series/397488#397488)